# Xamarin.iOS: Firebase push notifications not working

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms application with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS clients. For push notifications, I am using [FirebasePushNotificationPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin) library. It works perfectly on Android, but not on iOS.

On iOS the app simply closes down after the request to use push notifications. So: the "Allow/Don't allow" popup is shown, and when the user clicks on Allow, the app closes down. No exception is thrown or anything.

I have done every step in the setup instructions, but just to double-check, I will show you screenshots of everything:

1. **Firebase console:** I have registered my iOS app on the Firebase console and inputted all required fields (App ID, Bundle ID, App Store ID, App ID Prefix). I have also uploaded the APNs Authentication Key (but no certificates).

[image: Firebase Console app]
[image: Firebase Console app configuration]

2. **NuGet:** I have added [Plugin.FirebasePushNotification](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.FirebasePushNotification) package to both Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.iOS projects.

[image: VisualStudio NuGet packages]

3. **GoogleService-Info.plist:** I have added GoogleService-Info.plist (that I got from the Firebase console) to the Xamarin.iOS project and set its Build Action to `BundleResource`.

[image: VisualStudio GoogleService-Info.plist Properties]

4. **Info.plist:** I have enabled remote notification background mode and added FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled (and set it to No) in Info.plist.

[image: Info.plist]

5. **Entitlements.plist**: I have added production aps-environment entitlement.

[image: Entitlements.plist]

It is `production` (and not `development`) because I cannot run and debug the app, so the app is actually being uploaded every time to the App Store Connect and tested with TestFlight as an internal tester.

6. **Xamarin.iOS AppDelegate:** I initialize the package in `AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching` method, right after `LoadApplication(new App());`. The `false` parameter means that it will not auto register for notifications (it will be registered later manually).

[image: Xamarin.iOS AppDelegate]

I also override methods `RegisteredForRemoteNotifications`, `FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications`, `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` and call respected methods (as stated in the [Getting Started](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md#ios-initialization) instructions).

7. **Xamarin.Forms:** Now this is when all goes to hell on iOS. When it calls `CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();`, it shows the "Allow/Don't allow" popup, and after the user clicks "Allow", the app simply closes. No exception is thrown or anything (well, at least nothing gets caught in the try/catch statement). The app simply shuts down.

[image: Xamarin.Forms App.xaml.cs]

The interesting thing maybe is, that the FCM token is already (successfuly) created before all this and if I send a push message to that token (of that iOS app), the Firebase server returns `success`. So I'm guessing that the Firebase part is correct, but there is something wrong with the iOS and/or the library?

Any advice whatsoever will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about using this firebase nuget package instead? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging/ It is created by Xamarin. I used it successfully in a previous project.

Comment: I have already considered that, but the implementation would then also have to be done separately for Android... The library that I am currently using is implemented using the package that you mentioned. If nobody comes up with a solution, I will definitely try it.

Comment: Does anything show up in the device logs? See if the console spits out any system messages about why it killed the app.

Comment: I will check it when I get the chance.

Comment: it is work :     'LoadApplication(new App());
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone reading this: I have solved this problem by removing the [FirebasePushNotificationPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin) library, which apparently doesn't work on iOS. I have then implemented the notifications using the [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging/) package instead, following this [GettingStarted](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md) guideline.

Comment: Link for GettingStarted guideline is broke! =/

Comment: They changed the location of the docs. I've updated the link, check again.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key @GregaMohorko I have also combined your approach with this article and it works for me.

Comment: Did you remove the FirebasePushNotificationPlugin from the iOS project or the main Forms project? Because I am using the FirebasePushNotificationPlugin in my forms project and it works for my android project.

Comment: I removed it from the main Forms project and started using Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging in both Android and iOS.

Comment: When trying to use the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging `Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;` gives an Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error